# SVG Invert stroke colour based on background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG with a `stroke` which I want to invert to white when the background underneath it is blue.

[Here's the effect I'm aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESEMk.png)

The grey is a set colour from a CSS variable.

SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="25px" viewBox="0 0 25 210">
   <g>
     <path d="M -678 692 L 702 692" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="15 15" transform="rotate(270,12,692)" pointer-events="all"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

I've already attempted to add two separate SVGs; one having a white stroke for the blue section and another being grey for the body however the gap between the SVGs changes on different screen sizes which I do not want.

[Using two SVGs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4SzI.png)

I've also attempted to use a combination of the CSS `filter`, `backdrop-filter` and `mix-blend-mode` properties however I was unable to get the correct effect, as `filter` affects the whole SVG and `backdrop-filter` does not modify the path's stroke colour.

```css
header {
    display: block;
}

.header__nav-wrapper {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#122F76), to(#1941A2));
    background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #122F76, #1941A2);
    padding: 2.5rem 8rem 0 8rem;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
        height: 150px;
}

.header__wave {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.top-line {
      position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.top-line__line--left {
    left: 200px;
    top: -200px;
}

.top-line__line {
    position: absolute;
    stroke: #999;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__nav-wrapper"></div>
  <!-- Include svg wave -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="header__wave" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1920 80">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="mx-gradient-122f76-1-1941a2-1-e-0">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(18, 47, 118); stop-opacity: 1;" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(25, 65, 162); stop-opacity: 1;" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <path d="M 0 0 L 1920 0 L 1920 68 Q 1440 46.4 960 68 Q 480 89.6 0 68 L 0 12 Z" fill="url(#mx-gradient-122f76-1-1941a2-1-e-0)" pointer-events="all" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</header>
<div class="top-line">
  <div class="top-line__line top-line__line--left">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="25px" viewBox="0 0 25 400">
      <g>
        <path d="M -678 692 L 702 692" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="15 15" transform="rotate(270,12,692)" pointer-events="all"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/samuelmereau/pen/YzeMbVw) link if you need to look at the code.

If possible I'd really appreciate a CSS-only approach however I'm more than happy to use JavaScript if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: @RobertLongson I provided a link to the effect I'm aiming for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESEMk.png (this was diagrammed in draw.io, not written in HTML). The two separate SVGs did not achieve the effect as the gap between them was affected by the screen width. `filter` affected the whole SVG, not just the section on blue, while `backdrop-filter` did not affect the path's stroke. I'll update my post to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I use the dotted line as a mask on two `<rect>`. Beneath (defined first) are two `<rect>` that has the color that the dotted line is supposed to have.

The wave is also define as a mask and can be reused on the two `<rect>` that define the upper part of the SVG.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="header__wave" viewBox="0 0 200 80">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="g1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="navy" stop-opacity="1" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="navy" stop-opacity=".2" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="line">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="80" fill="white" />
      <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="5 2" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="wave">
      <rect width="200" height="31" fill="white" />
      <path transform="translate(0 30)" fill="white" d="M 0 0 L 200 0 L 200 7 Q 150 5 100 7 Q 50 9 0 7 Z" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="gray" width="200" height="79" />
  <rect fill="white" width="200" height="80" mask="url(#wave)" />
  <g mask="url(#line)">
    <rect fill="white" width="200" height="80" />
    <rect fill="url(#g1)" width="200" height="80" mask="url(#wave)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Looks great, exactly what I was after! Thank you heaps